# I get this error when I use npm install npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19041

Tags: npm

I'm getting this error when I run npm install, even when I try to upgrade my npm I get this error

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19041
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\jaydev\Desktop\Testreact\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "i"
npm ERR! node v14.15.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log

Answer (score -1):

I'm using node v12, I have the same error, but I fix it by:

- go to **C:\Users\username** find and delete folder **'~**
- go to **your\project\folder** find and delete folder **'~**
- re-open command prompt
- install again

I'm not sure that it work for you your node version, But it work for me, I hope that can help you.

Comment: wait what folder am I suppose to delete?

Comment: @JahmarLawrence What was your solution? I'm not seeing that folder either.